# 400 bad request when indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a series of documents into ElasticSearch.

510 objects are indexed properly (from ElasticHQ), but (at least) one is causing a 400 bad request error. This is the full stacktrace:

```
exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] http://localhost:9200/vins/vin/1465' in /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(145): Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))
#1 [internal function]: Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#2 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#3 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(53): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'request.error', Object(Guzzle\Common\Event))
#4 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(589): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('request.error', Object(Guzzle\Common\Event))
#5 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(378): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->processResponse(Array)
#6 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/EntityEnclosingRequest.php(49): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->setState('complete', Array)
#7 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(290): Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest->setState('complete', Array)
#8 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(248): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
#9 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(231): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages()
#10 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(215): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->executeHandles()
#11 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(109): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->perform()
#12 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(94): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->send()
#13 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(284): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->send()
#14 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(198): Guzzle\Http\Client->send(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest))
#15 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(162): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->send()
#16 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(98): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->sendRequest(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), false)
#17 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(162): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->performRequest('PUT', '/vins/vin/1465', Array, false)
#18 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/AbstractEndpoint.php(86): Elasticsearch\Transport->performRequest('PUT', '/vins/vin/1465', Array, Array)
#19 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(857): Elasticsearch\Endpoints\AbstractEndpoint->performRequest()
#20 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/modules/elasticsearch/classes/Indexers/VinIndexer.php(70): Elasticsearch\Client->index(Array)
#21 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/modules/elasticsearch/controllers/ControlElasticsearchService.php(16): VinIndexer->indexOne('1465')
#22 [internal function]: ControlElasticsearchService->indexOne('1465')
#23 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/module/controller/Controller.php(410): call_user_func(Array, '1465')
#24 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/Application.php(170): Controller->run(Array, false)
#25 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/Application.php(136): Application->startMainController()
#26 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/index.php(87): Application->run()
#27 {main}

Next exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception' with message '{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]","status":400}' in /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php:239
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(167): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->process4xxError(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException), false)
#1 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/GuzzleConnection.php(98): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->sendRequest(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), false)
#2 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php(162): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->performRequest('PUT', '/vins/vin/1465', Array, false)
#3 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/AbstractEndpoint.php(86): Elasticsearch\Transport->performRequest('PUT', '/vins/vin/1465', Array, Array)
#4 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php(857): Elasticsearch\Endpoints\AbstractEndpoint->performRequest()
#5 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/modules/elasticsearch/classes/Indexers/VinIndexer.php(70): Elasticsearch\Client->index(Array)
#6 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/modules/elasticsearch/controllers/ControlElasticsearchService.php(16): VinIndexer->indexOne('1465')
#7 [internal function]: ControlElasticsearchService->indexOne('1465')
#8 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/module/controller/Controller.php(410): call_user_func(Array, '1465')
#9 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/Application.php(170): Controller->run(Array, false)
#10 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/core/application/Application.php(136): Application->startMainController()
#11 /Users/nicolaswidart/Sites/Mestdagh_2/index.php(87): Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

It says document empty, but it isn't...
This is the object I'm trying to index, causing that error:

```
array (size=2)
  'body' => 
    array (size=29)
      'sNameLngFr' => string 'Pinot Blanc D'alsace   Stã©phane Berg' (length=37)
      'pPrix' => float 4.99
      'iPromotion' => int 0
      'pPromotion' => float 4.99
      'sColor' => string 'blancsec' (length=8)
      'sColorLngFr' => string 'Blanc Sec' (length=9)
      'sColorLngNl' => string 'Droge witte wijn' (length=16)
      'sProducerUrl' => string '' (length=0)
      'iVintage' => int 2012
      'sPackageType' => string '6bouteilles' (length=11)
      'sPackageTypeLngFr' => string '6 bouteilles' (length=12)
      'sPackageTypeLngNl' => string '6 flessen' (length=9)
      'sKeepingPotentialLngFr' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'sKeepingPotentialLngNl' => string '' (length=0)
      'sVolume' => string '75cl' (length=4)
      'pays' => 
        array (size=3)
          'iPays' => int 10
          'sNameLngFr' => string 'France' (length=6)
          'sNameLngNl' => string 'Frankrijk' (length=9)
      'region' => 
        array (size=3)
          'iRegion' => int 29
          'sNameLngFr' => string 'Alsace' (length=6)
          'sNameLngNl' => string 'Alsace' (length=6)
      'appellation' => 
        array (size=3)
          'iAppelation' => int 49
          'sNameLngFr' => string 'Alsace Pinot ou Klevner' (length=23)
          'sNameLngNl' => string 'Alsace Pinot ou Klevner' (length=23)
      'sProducer' => string 'S. BERG ORSCHWILLER' (length=19)
      'iKeepingPotential' => int 0
      'sCommentaireLngFr' => string '' (length=0)
      'sCommentaireLngNl' => string '' (length=0)
      'sExternalRef' => string '718182' (length=6)
      'sFood1' => string '13' (length=2)
      'sFood2' => string '8' (length=1)
      'sFood3' => string '3' (length=1)
      'sEanBarcode' => string '' (length=0)
      'iFamilyId' => int 71
      'sFullExternalRef' => string '00718182' (length=8)
  'id' => int 1465
```

When doing a random search on those 510 documents indexed I get:

```
array (size=3)
      'total' => int 61
      'max_score' => float 0.99237627
      'hits' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              '_index' => string 'vins' (length=4)
              '_type' => string 'vin' (length=3)
              '_id' => string '938' (length=3)
              '_score' => float 0.99237627
              '_source' => 
                array (size=29)
                  'sNameLngFr' => string 'Chateau Vieux Ligat' (length=19)
                  'pPrix' => float 5.89
                  'iPromotion' => int 0
                  'pPromotion' => float 5.89
                  'sColor' => string 'rougefruitÃ©' (length=12)
                  'sColorLngFr' => string 'Rouge FruitÃ©' (length=13)
                  'sColorLngNl' => string 'Fruitige rode wijn' (length=18)
                  'sProducerUrl' => string '' (length=0)
                  'iVintage' => int 2010
                  'sPackageType' => string '6bouteilles' (length=11)
                  'sPackageTypeLngFr' => string '6 bouteilles' (length=12)
                  'sPackageTypeLngNl' => string '6 flessen' (length=9)
                  'sKeepingPotentialLngFr' => string '2015' (length=4)
                  'sKeepingPotentialLngNl' => string '' (length=0)
                  'sVolume' => string '75 cl' (length=5)
                  'pays' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'iPays' => int 10
                      'sNameLngFr' => string 'France' (length=6)
                      'sNameLngNl' => string 'Frankrijk' (length=9)
                  'region' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'iRegion' => int 31
                      'sNameLngFr' => string 'Bordeaux' (length=8)
                      'sNameLngNl' => string 'Bordeaux' (length=8)
                  'appellation' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      'iAppelation' => int 71
                      'sNameLngFr' => string 'Bordeau' (length=7)
                      'sNameLngNl' => string 'Bordeau' (length=7)
                  'sProducer' => string 'SERGE SEGUIN' (length=12)
                  'iKeepingPotential' => int 0
                  'sCommentaireLngFr' => string '<p dir="LTR">Un vin rouge aux belles notes de fruits rouges. Fin et dÃ©licat, il accompagnera viandes rouges et fromages</p>' (length=124)
                  'sCommentaireLngNl' => string '<p>Een rode wijn met rode vruchtenaroma's. Fijn en delikaat, perfect met rood vlees en kaas.</p>' (length=96)
                  'sExternalRef' => string '711290' (length=6)
                  'sFood1' => string '3' (length=1)
                  'sFood2' => string '4' (length=1)
                  'sFood3' => string '6' (length=1)
                  'sEanBarcode' => string '9990259121902' (length=13)
                  'iFamilyId' => int 71
                  'sFullExternalRef' => string '00711290' (length=8)
          1 =>
```

So as shown, some properties are empty and it indexed fine.

Any reason to this error? On that particular object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
string 'Pinot Blanc D'alsace 
'<p>Een rode wijn met rode vruchtenaroma's. Fijn en delikaat, perfect met rood vlees en kaas.</p>'
```

These two lines have a forbiden char, try to escape them and it may work.

Comment: I tried removing the `'`, but the problem persisted. After further investigation it appeared to be the strtolower that caused the problems. Without it, it can index without a problem.